# OCaml function type with arrows ->

Tags: types, ocaml

I'm using OCaml StringMap.add function as follows:

```
let rec makecount l = function
    [] -> mymap
    | s::tl -> 
    if (not (StringMap.mem s mymap)) then
        StringMap.add s 1 makecount(tl)
    else
        StringMap.add s ((StringMap.find s mymap) + 1) makecount(tl)
```

I get the error, referring to the StringMap.add s 1 makecount(List.tl l):

```
Error: This function has type StringMap.key -> 'a -> 'a StringMap.t -> 'a StringMap.t   
It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'.
```

Firstly, can someone explain the formatting for the function type. What do those arrows mean? If someone can find the error too, that would be nice as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you write : StringMap.add s 1 (makecount (List.tl l)) ?
What happens is that makecount is considered as a argument in your code, whereas you want the result of makecount (List.tl l).

The arrows are saying that String.Map expects 3 arguments (respectively of types  StringMap.key , 'a , 'a StringMap.t) and returns a result of type 'a StringMap.t.

Comment: YES! That was the problem. Thanks for explaining the arrow thing as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
function
    []    -> ...
  | s::tl -> ...
```

is an anonymous function that matches its argument against `[]` and `s::tl`, and executes the first branch that "fits". `[]` will only match an empty list; `s::tl` matches any list with at least one element (`s`), where `tl` is the tail - the list you get when you chop off the head.

You assign this anonymous function taking an argument to `makecount l`; meaning `makecount` itself now wants two arguments (where you never use `l` again). The solution is simple: just delete `l`, and have `makecount` be a function that takes one argument (per above).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! It helped me understand the format of OCaml. Yes, that was part of the problem.